# Cold weather kofta?

Tags: middle-eastern-cuisine

I was given lamb kofta in my CSA share. It is spiced with coriander, cumin, garlic, paprika, and ginger.

I have limited experience with Middle Eastern cuisine, and I've always thought of it almost exclusively as warm-weather food. I can't wrap my head around a dish suitable for the 15-degree day we're having in NYC right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, you may be accustomed to discussion forums. Our model is different, we try to give objective answers to technical-ish problems encountered when cooking. The rules which humans make up around eating certain foods under certain circumstances are interesting from an anthropological point of view, and they do make a nice topic to muse about with friends. Sadly, this kind of conversation does not fit our format, and I don't see a question you can ask about your situation which would be on topic here.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with SE, and I had an inkling someone would claim this question is inappropriate. I think the answers so far highlight the "technical-ish" nature of this question; rather than musing, I think they're a great demonstration of the unique approach of SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of parts of the Middle East where it gets pretty chilly, snowy etc. when it's wintertime. I suppose the citizens there must have options in their cuisine to cover all times of the year.

If it's meaty, filling, and hot, and especially if it takes a long time cooking (heating up the house), wouldn't any dish be suitable for 15 degree weather?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other post - there is no hard and fast rule about which dish is appropriate for a certain time or temperature. Our notions about “cold / hot weather dishes” are based on what culture we grew up with and to a large extent on what was in season, available or could be preserved.

But if the idea of cooking the lamb now goes against your personal preferences, put it in the freezer and cook it at a time you are more comfortable with it. It’s spiced meat, it should easily keep in the freezer until summer.